# Gem Fire 6 to Gem Fire 8 Upgrade

Tags: java, gemfire

We have a Gem Fire 6 data, want to migrate it to Gem Fire 8 data. What are possible options for this?
We need this as our customers may not be happy to loose data in Gem Fire 6 servers.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

See the Pivotal GemFire User Guide here for more details... http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#getting_started/upgrade_from.html.  In particular, pay close attention to bullet #5.

Also keep in mind... http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#getting_started/version_compatiblity.html.

Disclaimer: I am not experienced, or an expert in upgrading GemFire, but...

I was thinking there maybe more than a few ways to accomplish this feat depending on the customer's UCs/requirements.

1 option is to do a big bang conversion and stream the data between an older GemFire cluster (e.g. 6.x) and a newer GemFire cluster (e.g. 8.1) using Spring XD.

Another option would be to "incrementally" migrate data from the old GemFire cluster to the new GemFire cluster on cache misses by setting up a CacheLoader in the new GemFire cluster cache Region(s) that serve as "cache clients" to the old GemFire cluster, corresponding cache Region.  Then when a "cache miss" occurs in the new Region, it will attempt to "load" the value from the old Region (hosted in the older cluster).  See section "Version Compatibility Between Clients and Servers" in http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#getting_started/version_compatiblity.html for further details.

Of course, both of these options, though doable, may not be recommended and I would encourage you to verify with the Pivotal EA/professional services team to be sure before you choose any approach.

I am just thinking outside the box and giving you ideas to consider, ;-)

Hope this helps,

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, we will consult Pivotal EA/professional services team before choosing any approach. Thanks.